# cscope: Cscope error: cscope: cannot read list size from file cscope.out

Tags: cscope

**Issue**:
I get the following error when I try to open a file in vim (version 7.3).

**cs_read_prompt EOF: Illegal seek
E609: Cscope error: cscope: cannot read list size from file cscope.out**

**Description**:
I created the cscope database "cscope.out" using the command "cscope -b -R". The file ~/.vim/plugin/cscope_maps.vim contains the command "cs add cscope.out" to add the cscope database. When I try to open one of the source files, I get the error mentioned above.

uname -a

Linux 2.6.16.60-0.58.1.3835.0.PTF.638363-smp #1 SMP Wed Dec 2 12:27:56 UTC 2009 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

What could be the problem here?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

Mine got resolved when I found that the size of the "cscope.out" file was too LARGE(~2.5GB).
Create a separate cscope DB for larger sub folders. And add all DBs separately using ":cs add ".

Note: Reverse index(cscope -b -q) creates larger files.

Answer (score -1):

One of the cases where you encounter this error is: if you have a directory that has **space(s)** in the **directory name** (even in the path of your source folder) then rename the directory without space(s) and retry.

Answer (score -1):

There may be multiple version of cscope on your system. You may check various location of your cscope binary by

```
whereis cscope
```

Then add one of this path in your .vimrc

```
vim ~/.vimrc
set csprg=/path/to/your/desired/cscope
```