# Cscope error: cscope: cannot read list size from file cscope.out

Tags: linux, cscope

There's an exact questioned that is already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11132481/cscope-cscope-error-cscope-cannot-read-list-size-from-file-cscope-out)!, but with no detailed solution, so asking again. I followed [this](http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse451/12sp/tutorials/tutorial_cscope.html)! tutorial:

```
find . -name "*.c" -o -name "*.cpp" -o -name "*.h" -o -name "*.hpp" > cscope.files
cscope -q -R -b -i cscope.files
cscope -d
```

when I execute the last command, I get an error:
    cscope: can not read list size from file cscope.out.

files sizes:

```
$ ls -l | grep cscope
-rw-r--r--   1 tnsharma  wheel     8230153 May 29 11:13 cscope.files
-rw-r--r--   1 tnsharma  wheel   280810496 May 29 11:39 cscope.in.out
-rw-r--r--   1 tnsharma  wheel  3471526675 May 29 11:39 cscope.out
-rw-r--r--   1 tnsharma  wheel  1929521640 May 29 11:39 cscope.po.out
```

Any idea how to make this work?
-Thanks

Update: I am able to use cscope in the sub folders. But don't know how to link the cscope.out files across the sub folders to make it global.

Comment: Can you show `head -n 20` of your cscope.out file? (I have src code http://sources.debian.net/src/cscope/15.8a-2/src/main.c?hl=940#L932 ) Also I can recommend you to use [`cindex`/`csearch` - codesearch project](https://code.google.com/p/codesearch/) from RE4 author Russ Cox for fast searching in large codebases.

Comment: @osgx: I faced this error during my summer internship while working on the firm's codebase. I don't have access to it now. I'll try it out again on my machine to check if I get it right.

Comment: You cscope.out is just too big (>2.5 GB). You should delete '`-b`' option to make it smaller; also you can add several `cscope.out`s to vim by `:cs add dir1/cscope.out`, `:cs add dir2/cscope.out`. And index by cindex/csearch is much better, it supports regexps (like grep), and can index even whole Debian codebase: http://codesearch.debian.net

Answer (score 0):

Your `cscope.out` is too large for it to work.

Try reducing the number of files that you parse when doing `cscope -R` or `-b` by creating a `cscope.files` files.

Answer (score 0):

I have given a solution in case where your **directory name**, or **the path of the directory** has **space(s)**. Rename directory without space(s) and retry. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/30423629/3936129